# venn generating software

Tags: animation, diagrams

I need venn generating software for Creating  venn diagrams and Animations for venn diagrams.

its should be free ;-)

Comment: Please can you be more detailed with your questions? One line questions are less likely to get answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Easy Venn Diagram Software](http://www.smartdraw.com/specials/venn.htm)

Create great-looking Venn diagrams, marketing charts, and more in minutes with SmartDraw.

[image]

- Automatic Drawing
- Click simple commands and SmartDraw builds your Venn diagram for you, automatically.
- Automatic Formatting
- Add or remove a shape, and SmartDraw realigns and arranges all the elements so that everything looks great.
- Quick-Start Templates
- Dozens of professionally-designed Venn diagram examples make you instantly productive.  -  - Simply choose the template that is most similar to your project, and customize it to suit your needs.
- Free Support

Or should it be webbased?

Comment: is it possible port that into Web pages and i can able to create the venn diagram with animation mode

Comment: Krish, how do you mean port into a webpage? If it's an image, off course you can. Do you want a web based Venn generator?

Answer (score 1):

Google Chart API for **[Venn diagrams](http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/chart/types.html#venn)**

Specify a venn diagram with

```
cht=v
```

Supply one data set where:

- The first three values specify the relative sizes of three circles: A, B, and C.
- The fourth value specifies the area of A intersecting B.
- The fifth value specifies the area of A intersecting C.
- The sixth value specifies the area of B intersecting C.
- The seventh value specifies the area of A intersecting B intersecting C.

---

**Description:**

- In this example, the value 100 specifies the first circle, the value 80 specifies the second circle, and the value 60 specifies the third circle. The values 30, 25 and 20 specify the areas of overlap between each pair of circles. The value 10 specifies the area of overlap between all three circles.For information on available parameters for Venn diagrams, see [Optional parameters by chart type.](http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/chart/basics.html#optional_param_by_chart_type)

**Example**:

[image]

---

For your information:

**Developer's Guide**

The Google Chart API lets you dynamically generate charts. To see the Chart API in action, open up a browser window and copy the following URL into the address bar:

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=t:60,40&chs=250x100&chl=Hello|World
```

Press the Enter or Return key and - presto! - you should see the following image:

[image]

Comment: I'm no expert in Google Code things, but I'm sure you can use a chart generator from their site